# Silverlight ListBox DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight-4.0, listbox, datatemplate

I have a Silverlight 4 ListBox with a created DataTemplate attached to it that correctly shows the items I want.

I would like to be able to have each Item in the list display differently according to a value in the object that is represented by the DataContext. I was originally looking at altering the DataTemplate on a per item basis, but I think my logic here is flawed.

What is the best way to approach this? Is a Listbox the best way to represent the collection given that I want a potentially different look per item?

Answer (score 0):

I think ur looking for template selector in Silverlight .

Please follow below url http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLTemplateSelector.aspx

-Mahender